# Laravel how to split array into two based on the key value

Tags: php, laravel, multipartform-data, laravel-8

Hello guys I am working on a laravel project that requires user to submit data with files in a page. There are multiple form will be submitted at once when user click submit, I am using formData to separate the files and other normal input when submit

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (var key in this.equipments) {
    formData.append('id_'+key, JSON.stringify(this.equipments[key]));
  }
  this.equipments.forEach((item, idx) => {
    formData.append("file_" + idx, item.New_Cert);
  });
  axios
    .post("/equipments/calibration", formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
```

This is the output I getting in my backend with request->all()
[image]

May I ask how can I separate this request array into two based on the key value?
Currently the array structure is like

```
   [
    "id_0" => ".."
    "id_1" => ".."
    ....
    "file_0" =>"..."
    "file_1"=>""...."
    ....
    ]
```

can I divide it into two array so that I will have

1. id array

   [
   "id_0"=>"",
   "id_1"=>"",
   ...
   ]
2. file array

   [
   "file_0"=>"",
   "file_1"=>"",
   ..
   ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

using key value get index as key,
check substring and save into new arrays

```
<?php

$array = [
  "id_0" => "..",
  "id_1" => "..",
  "file_0" =>"...",
  "file_1"=>"....",
];

$id_arr = [];
$file_arr = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  if(substr($key, 0, 3) == "id_")
  {
    $id_arr[$key] = $value; 
  }
  else if(substr($key, 0, 5) == "file_")
  {
    $file_arr[$key] = $value; 
  }
}


var_dump($id_arr);
var_dump($file_arr);
```